# Getting deep children FormInput components

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I'm still extending react-admin `TabbedForm` and as I need custom layout, I need to access the `FormInput`s in my layout from `TabbedForm` so that the `findTabsWithErrors` function works well with my layout.

Right now, that function writes :

```
export const findTabsWithErrors = (
    state,
    props,
    collectErrorsImpl = collectErrors
) => {
    const errors = collectErrorsImpl(state, props);

    return Children.toArray(props.children).reduce((acc, child) => {
        const inputs = Children.toArray(child.props.children);

        if (inputs.some(input => errors[input.props.source])) {
            return [...acc, child.props.label];
        }

        return acc;
    }, []);
};
```

It expects `FormInput` components to be exactly 2 levels down the children tree.

In my case they should be 3 levels down but maybe I wan't to be able to not rely on the depth of hierarchy to get the `FormInput` components.

I'd like a way to get all children that are `FormInput` components, kind of what we do with DOM, no matter how deep they are nested.

So what's the react way of doing this ? Should I use refs ? I don't know...

Answer (score 1):

This is something I want to work on since a long time as I'm not satisfied with our current implementation. I think there are two ways to do that:

One would be to rely on React Context with the `FormTab` components providing methods for the inputs to **register** (*hey I belong to you, `FormTab`*). However, I think this kinda breaks the top-down only react flow.

The other would be to *duplicate* the information about what inputs belong to what `FormTab`, maybe a `fields` prop which would be an array of the inputs names in that tab. However this would make dynamic form difficult.

As a last resort, you'll have to implement your own `TabbedForm`

Comment: I did implement my own `TabbedForm` but it's so nasty... It's a copy of react-admin's with a different loop getting inputs.

Comment: I thought of making the inputs register to the tab, I think it would be a pretty simple api. I hope I'll get some time try an implementation. Another dirty way would be to walk through children top->down until a maxDepth is reached and look for the `source` property, or some other custom prop. But that's not 'clean' either.

Comment: has there been any progress on that matter ?

Comment: Did you come up with new ideas ? I implemented a CustomForm which passes the `renderInput` function to its children so that the layout can be whatever I want. It could also register inputs, I'm willing to implement it but I'd need pointers as I don't know how to use react contexts. Is there already a form context I should use? Or components with similar behaviours in ra that I could inspire from?

Comment: No and it will probably only happen in next major version

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a library that can help you with that case.

https://fernandopasik.com/react-children-utilities/deep-filter

```
const inputs = deepFilter(props.children, child => child.type === 'input')
```